# Using MATCH to build cell range returns #VALUE

Tags: excel, match

I have a formula which finds the 10 highest values using the LARGE function, with a set cell range.  SALESNew is 52 weeks of figures and the k-th largest value is in SALES Summ $C...

```
=LARGE('2015SALESNew'!$D$250:$BC$250,'SALES Summ'!$C6)
```

I need to extend this to dynamically select the row on SALESNew, based upon the product range.  I have tried various methods of building the cell range, all of which return the correct result when used on their own, but #VALUE is returned if I use it within the LARGE formula.

Examples below:

```
=LARGE(("'2015SALESNew'!$D$"&G43&":$BC$"&G43),'SALES Summ'!$C43)

$G43 contains =MATCH($A38,'2015SALESNew'!A:A,0)
```

The 3 methods I have tried below all return the correct range

```
    ('2015SALESNew'!$D$255:$BC$255) but the formula result is always #VALUE.

="'2015SALESNew'!$D$"&G43&":$BC$"&G43
="'2015SALESNew'!$D$"&MATCH($A38,'2015SALESNew'!A:A,0)&":$BC$"&MATCH($A38,'2015SALESNew'!A:A,0)
=CONCATENATE("'2015SALESNew'!$D$",MATCH($A38,'2015SALESNew'!A:A,0),":$BC$",MATCH($A38,'2015SALESNew'!A:A,0))
```

What am I missing with the cell range not being read correctly?

Comment: First of all, could you please format your formulas as code, that makes them easier to read. Just put 4 spaces infront of them.

Comment: Secondly, why are there double quotation marks in your formula ( " )? I think you should remove those, as you are indicating now that some references are text, instead of the reference.

Comment: @Luuklag - I need to use the double quotes to build the cell range.  I've also answered my own question by looking at other formulas I've used in the past- wrapping the formula with INDIRECT solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I find the best way to build a dynamic range reference is by using the `INDEX` function.  As the help file says - Index (reference form) **Returns the reference of the cell at the intersection of a particular row and column.**

So, as an example, `=INDEX($J:$J,5)` will return a reference at the intersection of row 5 in the range $J:$J - i.e. $J$5.
Add another INDEX to this formula, say the intersection of row 10 in the range $N:$N and you have a range of cells referenced:  `=INDEX($J:$J,5):INDEX($N:$N,10)`.
Run this through Evaluate Formula and it will show you the range $J$5:$N$10 - wrap it in a SUM function and it will add up all values in that range.

Now to make it dynamic - the formula `COUNTA($N:$N)` will count all cells in column N that are not empty.  Providing you have no blanks in column N this will effectively give you the last row containing data in column N.
So now we can rewrite the formula to read `=$J$5:INDEX($N:$N,COUNTA($N:$N))`.
I've changed J5 to a constant - might as well if it's not going to change - and the second reference to the last cell containing data in column N (providing there's no blanks in column N).  This now references J5:N10 in my example.
Wrap this in a LARGE function `=LARGE($J$5:INDEX($N:$N,COUNTA($N:$N)),3)` and it displays the 3rd largest number in my range.

**Edit:** As an added bonus the INDEX function is non-volatile, while the similar OFFSET function and the INDIRECT function are volatile - causing an overhead whenever you calculate.
http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm

> A Volatile Function is one that causes recalculation of the formula in
>   the cell where it resides every time Excel recalculates.  This occurs
>   regardless of whether the precedent data and formulas on which the
>   formula depends have changed, or whether the formula also contains
>   non-volatile functions.